# Sharing common variable between 2 functions in multithreaded environment

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am writing a multi threaded use case, where loop runs continuously in `entry()` function and ends when `exit_loop()` is called. In the below example, `entry()` is called with two threads and the execution of both the thread ends when `exit_loop()` is called.

Now I would like to change this a bit by exiting only one thread when `exit_loop()` is called first, i.e. `entry()` called from `thread[2]` still remains which can be terminated when `exit_loop()` is called again. To make these two threads independent I could move the `static int loop` to local scope. But I am struck in the way of communicating the `loop` status between `entry()` and `exit_loop()`.

Want to share a common variable between two functions, which must not affect and interfere with multi threaded use case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

static int loop = 1;
void* entry()
{
    int count = 0;
    while(loop)
    {
        count ++;
        printf("\n Count %d, loop %d",count, loop);
    }
}

void exit_loop()
{
    printf("\n Calling exit loop: %d", loop);
    loop = 0;
    printf("\n loop is null %d", loop);
}

void main()
{   
    sem_t* loop1;
    sem_t* loop2;
    pthread_t threadID[5];
    loop1 = sem_open("sem1", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0);
    if (loop1 != SEM_FAILED)
    {   
        printf("\n Created sem 1");
        pthread_create(&threadID[1], NULL, &entry, NULL);// creating thread 1

    printf("Created thread \n ");
}
else
{
    printf("\n Failed to create Semaphore");
}
sem_close(loop1);

loop2 = sem_open("sem2", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0);
if (loop2 != SEM_FAILED)
{   
    printf("\n Created sem 2");
    pthread_create(&threadID[2], NULL, &entry, NULL);//creating thread 2

    printf("Created thread \n ");
}
else
{
    printf("\n Failed to create Semaphore");
}
sem_close(loop2);

printf("Creating exit thread \n");
exit_loop();// exit of both thread

pthread_join(threadID[1],NULL);
pthread_join(threadID[2],NULL);
}
```

Comment: One way is to have a seperate variable for each thread. e.g `int loop[2];`. Then call `exit_thread(0)` or `exit_thread(1)` to set the required `loop` entry. Finally, declare entry correctly: It should be `void *entry(void *arg)` as specified in the [`pthread_create` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). That way you can create each thread with a different `arg` value to tell it which `loop` variable to check.

Comment: Why are you using semaphore? The functionality that you want to achieve can be done with a little modification, you need to have an argument in `exit_loop()` that can store thread ID and then call `exit_loop()` with the thread ID that you want to terminate. You also need to call `pthread_cancel()` with the provided thread ID. Please refer `pthread_cancel` man page.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two threads which need to be stopped independently, you need two `loop` variables.

In each case, you need a **mutex** to protect accesses to the shared `loop` variable to prevent undefined behaviour, because the variable is accessed from two threads (the one reading it and the one writing it).

Declare your mutex alongside the variable it protects:

```
struct protected_loop_var{
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
  int value;
};

struct protected_loop_var loop1={PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,1};
struct protected_loop_var loop2={PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,1};
```

Then, before accessing each `loop` variable, lock the mutex, and unlock the mutex afterwards. It is probably easiest to write separate functions for accessing loop to encapsulate this.

```
static int read_loop(struct protected_loop_var* loop){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&loop->mutex);
    int value=loop->value;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&loop->mutex);
    return value;
}

static void write_loop(struct protected_loop_var* loop,int newval){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&loop->mutex);
    loop->value=newval;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&loop->mutex);
}
```

Then your `while` in `entry` can say `while(read_loop(&loopvar))`, and in `exit_loop` you can write `write_loop(&loopvar,0)` instead of `loop=0` where `loopvar` is either `loop1` or `loop2` as appropriate.

If you need to run the same code on each thread then you can pass the address of the loop variable to that thread via the `void*` argument.

Other patterns may work for this specific case, but a mutex is the general tool to use for protecting multithreaded accesses to a shared variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will not solve my problem I believe. Even with this all threads have access to the common variable `loop`. So when `exit_loop()` is called for the first time by updating `loop` in `write_loop()`. Both the alive threads reads it as false and the problem still continues

Comment: Updated answer to cover multiple loop variables